# How to make text blocks move from one place to another in Android?

Tags: android, jquery, css, user-interface

I am fairly new to Android Development,specially UI.

I am making this small application where I have some words at the bottom of the page and when I click on them they should align on top in the order in which those were clicked.`

I am attaching an image where two words were clicked and are on top while others are still to be clicked.`

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You want me to download a picture?  Why not upload it to a free image service or attach it to your question.

Comment: I didnt do it but it's uploaded now.Shows with the question.